# "Error: Cannot find module" While Using Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My node application does not run when i run node index.js

File index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '<my-token>';
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})


bot.login(token);
```

This is the stacktrace of the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Thela\Desktop\Discord UWU\run'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
```

Comment: Did you ran `npm i discord.js`?

Comment: Yes I Did @mthrsj

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Add your exact question by editing your post.

Comment: @CodePortal I'm trying to reproduce your error and I couldn't. The token that I've removed from your question isn't in the right format. Go to the "Bot" tab in Discord application dashboard an get the token below the bot name

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are starting the bot incorrectly. Make sure to do `node <path to bot main file>`

e.g.

`node "C:\Users\ExampleUser\Documents\ExampleBot\app.js"`, with app.js being the file you posted. Make sure to switch this all out with your own files/paths

To make it easier, you can also `cd` to the corresponding folder and run node app.js from there.

Comment: To make it easier, you can also `cd` to the corresponding folder and run `node app.js` from there.

Comment: @TheNewGuy added that to my answer.